# powermock dependencies for playframework app

Tags: dependencies, playframework, powermock

I try to configure dependencies for my playframework application to use **powemock**.

In my **dependencies.yml**:

require:

```
- play
...
- org.powermock -> powermock-mockito-release-full 1.4.9
- org.powermock -> powermock-module-junit4 1.4.9
...
```

I have test class:

```
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.**PowerMockRunner**;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static play.test.FunctionalTest.GET;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyStaticTest.MyStaticClass.class)
public class TagsTest extends FunctionalTest {

 ...
}
```

The problem is: My code **can not see** **PowerMockRunner** class.

Also, reading [this](http://mavenhub.com/c/org/powermock/modules/junit4/powermockrunner) article:

I have added this code to **dependencies.yml** as well (but it does'n help me):

```
repositories:
    ...
    - sonatype:
        type: http
        artifact: "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases"
```

So, how to configure my dependencies to be that resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using "powermock-api-mockito" instead of "powermock-mockito-release-full".

Comment: it also works if put ONLY org.powermock -> powermock-module-junit4 1.4.9